# Removing a entire row from a structure

Tags: struct, matlab

I created a structure containing 7 variables by using the multpots function in the BRML toolkit. The structure represents a joint probability distribution function. I would like to remove the rows that has 0 probability. How do I do this in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a struct to hold data and each field corresponds to a variable, you can delete the row having 0 probability in this way:

```
testData([testdata.probability] = 0) = [];
```

Where `testdata` variable holds the struct of data. Another way to do so is:

```
newTestData= subsetstruct(testData,testData.probability = 0);
```